# Blank screen after Sleep/Hibernate on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, grub2, screen, uuid

I have the problem that if I sleep or hibernate on my pavillon G7 AMD A6-4400m apu with radeon hd graphics × 2 ,

the screen will never turn on again, backlight is on but lcd stays black.

I tried to diable suspend and only turn off the display and lock the session but that didn't help.
I tried Ubuntu MATE, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Linux Mint and it does it on all of those but never on Windows 7.
There are no BIOS settings for the display on this machine.
I tried ctrl +  alt + F1 and alt + ctrl + Del and it didn't work either.    PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I close the lid, the screen will not turn on. I followed the instructions given in Ubuntu FAQs and it worked in one shot. This will  work for the new Ubuntu 18.0.x.

1. Pull up a Terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```

   to pull up the boot loader configuration.
2. Look for the line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
   ```

   and make sure it looks like this:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=41e86209-3802-424b-9a9d-d7683142dab7"
   ```
3. Save the file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>y</kbd>. You can use this UUID.
4. Run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   and wait for it to finish.
5. Run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
   ```

   and make sure to add:

   ```
   resume=UUID=41e86209-3802-424b-9a9d-d7683142dab7
   ```

   (with your UUID of course in place of mine if you want).
6. Save the file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>y</kbd>.
7. Run:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
8. Reboot!

Comment: Please provide a link to the FAQ. Please indicate in your answer the purpose of the partition of the UUID you mention. How will one know which UUID to use?

Comment: Which Ubuntu faq did you follow?

Comment: I do not find the faq again, but the uuid part has been edited to clarify. Thanks @user68186