# How do I get a device's UUID?

Tags: suspend, screen, amdgpu, gpu-driver, uuid

When returning from sleep mode the LCD of my laptop shows only snowflakes (like analog tv with no signal). Unless I restart it nothing changes, no display output. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140497/blank-screen-after-sleep-hibernate-on-ubuntu-18-04) question where the author is using `sudo nano / etc / default / grub` to output the boot loader configuration and add a device to resume. He is not specific about which device UUID is using, I suppose it's the GPU wich has to resume,but it may be the screen. I will try both of them to see which one will work, but how do I get their UUIDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question you've linked, the UUID used is the one of the swap partition. So, in order to fix your problem using the provided solution, you would have to find the UUID of your swap partition.
The easiest way to do that would be to execute the following command:

`sudo blkid | grep swap`

Which will output something similar to:

`/dev/sdb4: UUID="2ffc1e3c-8a56-41bc-914a-79efe08b8a52" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="5e43fe42-04"`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately adding that UUID to boot-loader didn't solve my problem.