# Ubuntu 20.04 - Hibernate mode does not work (pc-TOSHIBA-SATELLITE-C55-C)

Tags: suspend, hibernate

I have Ubuntu 20.04  I want  my pc to hibernate/sleep mode . How ever each time I press the suspend butten. My pc gets into sleep mode but when I try to wake him up ,the screen get very dark and then I need to reboot my pc  I tried  changing the brightness but that did not work.

My pc :  TOSHIBA-SATELLITE-C55-C.

other info : [pc info pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij4hv.png)

those are the things I found ,but none of them fixed my problem :

1)[18.04 Screen remains blank after wake up from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032633/18-04-screen-remains-blank-after-wake-up-from-suspend)

2)[Kubuntu 20.04 Black Screen After Sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247510/kubuntu-20-04-black-screen-after-sleep)

3)[Blank screen after Sleep/Hibernate on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140497/blank-screen-after-sleep-hibernate-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I tried doing this manuel :
[How to enable hibernate option in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04/1312421#1312421)

but now after the reboot I cant load the pc ,I get this eror :
[image]

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1312421/43926

Comment: Now my computer is stuck  at the UBUNTU logo . how to return before this changes ? :-(

Comment: How bi is your swapfile or are you using a swap partition?

Comment: The worst that ever happened to me is that the contents of RAM was larger than my swapfile and the system just rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

I am using hibernation on thinkpads, but it takes some steps before it works:

I do not use swap files. Never worked. So a dedicated swap partition is needed for these instructions. The size of the swap partition must be **at least** as large as your RAM

1. After installing copy the uuid entry from fstab. It is represented
   as xxx below. The commands presume you are su or sudo...
2. Create file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and add the line
   `Resume=UUID=xxxx`
3. Execute update-initramfs -u
4. In `/etc/default/grub` set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash
   resume=UUID=xxxx"
5. Execute update-grub
6. Change contents
   of`/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`:

> [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
> ResultActive=yes
>
> [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
> ResultActive=yes

Note: The "Disable hibernate" sections can be removed -or not

Reboot, then try: `systemctl hibernate`

If that works, you can change your settings (e.g. Lid close to hibernation).

Since Ubuntu 18 I am getting an grub error after a sucessful hibernation. This is due to a recordfail. To eliminate this problem I've done the following:

create `/etc/systemd/system/use-10_grub_common.service`file

```
[Unit]
Description=Execute the /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub_common script after hibernation.
After=hibernate.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common thaw

[Install]
WantedBy=hibernate.target
```

Enable that: systemctl enable use-10_grub_common

Disclaimer: Works with Intel GPU, **NOT** with Nivdia (on my laptops at least)