# Blank screen with cursor after suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I've been expressing issues with my ubuntu machine. whenever I suspend and close the lid and open the lid and look at the screen. It shows only a blank screen with cursor. I tried ctrl+f1 or ctrl+f7. none of them could bring back the console or GUI back. I also tried a couple of solutions online but they didn't help. How do I get it fixed? Can someone please guide me through the steps? Thanks.

I tried the following solutions:
[Blank screen after Sleep/Hibernate on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140497/blank-screen-after-sleep-hibernate-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I also did sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall but still nothing worked.

I'm on ubuntu 20.04 LTE. I disabled nvidia drivers and my system is intel 11th gen tiger lake.

I'm using 5.14.0-1027-oem kernel, So it's a HWE kernel stack. I'm not sure about any recent changes. it's been almost 2 months, I'm holding the power button to do a force shutdown. I was so annoyed by this that I have to come here and write a post about this.

I haven't switched to 5.18 or 5.15 cause wifi is not working in those kernel.

My system configuration
CPU: Quad Core 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 (-MT MCP-)
speed/min/max: 903/400/4200 MHz Kernel: 5.14.0-1027-oem x86_64 Up: 2h 40m
Mem: 4567.3/15751.8 MiB (29.0%) Storage: 1.14 TiB (18.7% used) Procs: 350
Shell: bash 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38

Comment: @guiverc I'm currently using GA kernel stack. and not sure when last time suspend resume actually worked for me.

Comment: if you are using wayland, try switching to xorg.

Comment: hey @ManOnTheMoon I'm using xorg currently. it's happening on both

Comment: you mentioned, you tried ctrl+f1 or ctrl+f7. the correct keys are: Ctrl+ALT+f5 on the black screen to enter your tty. (Ctrl+ALT+f1 to return). However, if there were typos, you can try this: [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1406212/1588972) while using nvidia drivers.

Comment: Thanks @ManOnTheMoon I tried the same but it still didn't work with that key combination  as well. nvidia drivers I have removed completely still the issue persists.